# comparing fields from different entities

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dynamics-crm-365

I am comparing fields from two different Entities,so that if the values are different then the field on form 1 gets set to what the field value is on the other  form.The problem is that although the logic seems right for some of the blocks it refuses to continue to the next if/else block unless the previous value changed.

So it goes to the blocks that check the state and country with no problems regardless if either are changed.However unless the state or country is changed(or country is commented out) it does not continue to the primary specialty to get check those values. Not sure what I'm missing here. I've made sure that nothing is nested and that all the logic actually works.

```
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("about to check state");
            if (getFieldValue("hc_stateid") == null && result["_hc_state_value"] != null) {// checling if value is null on tni becacuse the else if wouldnt execute b/c no id
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("its null");
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_stateid").
                  setValue([
                      {
                          id: result["_hc_state_value"],
                          name: result["_hc_state_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                          entityType: result["_hc_state_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                      }]);
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("state changes");
            }

            else if (result["_hc_state_value"] != getFieldValue("hc_stateid")[0].id.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").toString().toLowerCase()) {//tni has a value


                if (result["_hc_state_value"] == null) {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_stateid").setValue(null);
                }
                else {


                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_stateid").
                        setValue([
                            {
                                id: result["_hc_state_value"],
                                name: result["_hc_state_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                                entityType: result["_hc_state_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                            }]);
                    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("state changes");
                }
            }


            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("about to check country");
            /*if (getFieldValue("hc_countryid") == null && result["_hc_country_value"] != null)
            {
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_countryid").
                        setValue([
                            {
                                id: result["_hc_country_value"],
                                name: result["_hc_country_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                                entityType: result["_hc_country_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                            }]);
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("country changed");

            }
            else if (result["_hc_country_value"] != getFieldValue("hc_countryid")[0].id.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").toString().toLowerCase()) {
                if (result["_hc_country_value"] == null) {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_countryid").setValue(null);
                }
                else {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_countryid").
                        setValue([
                            {
                                id: result["_hc_country_value"],
                                name: result["_hc_country_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                                entityType: result["_hc_country_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                            }]);
                    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("country changed");
                }
            } */

            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("about to check prim spec");
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("prim specialty: " + (result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value"] != getFieldValue("hc_primaryspecialtyid")[0].id.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").toString().toLowerCase()).toString());
            if (getFieldValue("hc_primaryspecialtyid") == null && result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value"] != null) {
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_primaryspecialtyid").
                      setValue([
                          {
                              id: result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value"],
                              name: result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                              entityType: result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                          }]);
            }

            else if (result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value"] != getFieldValue("hc_primaryspecialtyid")[0].id.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").toString().toLowerCase()) {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("inside else if");
                if (result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value"] == null) {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_primaryspecialtyid").setValue(null);
                }
                else {
                    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("prime spec");
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_primaryspecialtyid").
                        setValue([
                            {
                                id: result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value"],
                                name: result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                                entityType: result["_hc_primaryspecialty_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                            }]);
                }
            }
            else {

            }

            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("after prim spec");
```

Comment: Were you able to debug it? Any errors?

Comment: I was able to debug it and no errors .it was really weird it kept completely  skipping over some of the conditions.Somehow i remedied it by adding empty else if statements and that forced it t continue. Makes no sense but ill take it.

Answer (score 0):

> so in order for me to get it to work I had to add empty else if conditions .It forced it to continue and check the other conditions. This makes no sense to me, but couldn't figure out another way to get around it.

```
            if (getFieldValue("hc_stateid") == null && result["_hc_state_value"] != null) {// checling if value is null on tni becacuse the else if wouldnt execute b/c no id

                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_stateid").
                  setValue([
                      {
                          id: result["_hc_state_value"],
                          name: result["_hc_state_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                          entityType: result["_hc_state_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                      }]);
                save = true;
            }
            else if (getFieldValue("hc_stateid") == null && result["_hc_state_value"] == null) {
                //this is needed otherwise it does not continue to check conditons
            }

            else if (result["_hc_state_value"] != getFieldValue("hc_stateid")[0].id.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").toString().toLowerCase()) {//tni has a value


                if (result["_hc_state_value"] == null) {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_stateid").setValue(null);
                    save = true;
                }
                else {


                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_stateid").
                        setValue([
                            {
                                id: result["_hc_state_value"],
                                name: result["_hc_state_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                                entityType: result["_hc_state_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                            }]);
                    save = true; 
                }
            }
            else {

            }




            if (getFieldValue("hc_countryid") == null && result["_hc_country_value"] != null || getFieldValue("hc_countryid") != null && result["_hc_country_value"] == null) {
                if (result["_hc_country_value"] == null) {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_countryid").setValue(null);
                    save = true;
                }
                else {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_countryid").
                        setValue([
                            {
                                id: result["_hc_country_value"],
                                name: result["_hc_country_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                                entityType: result["_hc_country_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                            }]);
                    save = true; 
                }
            }
            else if (getFieldValue("hc_countryid") == null && result["_hc_country_value"] == null) {
                //this is needed otherwise it does not continue to check conditons
            }

            else if (getFieldValue("hc_countryid")[0].id.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").toString().toLowerCase() != result["_hc_country_value"]) {

                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_countryid").
                    setValue([
                        {
                            id: result["_hc_country_value"],
                            name: result["_hc_country_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                            entityType: result["_hc_country_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"]
                        }]);
                save = true; 
            }
            else {

            }
```